# Trouble Storing arguments from Query string in C++

Tags: c++, cgi

I'm trying to parse a query string and store each argument in a specific string (such as the apr), but i'm having a hard time figuring it out. Right now I am able to display each argument from the URL like: ...assign09.cgi?apr=2&term=4&amount=7. I am able to get '2' '4' and '7' out of this, but whenever I try to assign a value to a string, I get an internal server error. Also, I think I am running off of the string because I get a '?' at the end of my output from my for loop.

My main question is: Is this a good way to parse the query string to get what I want?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstdlib>
 using namespace std;

 int main ()
 {
  cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
  string s = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
  string apr;
  string loanTerm;
  string loanAmount;
  string monthlyPayment;

  // apr, loanTerm, and monthlyPayment
  string args[3];
  cout << "<html>\n";
  cout << "<head>\n";
  cout << "<title>Hello World - First CGI Program</title>\n";
  cout << "</head>\n";
  cout << "<body>\n";
  cout << "<h1>Monthly Mortgage</h1>\n";
  cout << "<p>" << s << "</p>\n";
  for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == '=')
       {
          for(int k = i + 1; s[k] != '&'; k++)
         {
            cout << "<p>" << s[k] << "</p>";
         }
      }
   }

   cout << "</body>\n";
   cout << "</html>\n";

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Your `for(int k...` loop access an invalid entry, `s[k]` on the last `for (int i...` iteration.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. How do I stop it at the end of the string? I tried using null but that didn't work...

Comment: Beef up your `for (k` loop condition.  The value of `k` cannot be more than `s.length()-1`.  `for (int k = i+1; (k < s.length()) && (s[k] != '&'); ++k)`